# POST response not what it should be using urllib in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, urlencode, urllib

I'm trying to download the webpage from my university that gets returned when you search for classes. The website is here: http://websoc.reg.uci.edu/perl/WebSoc.

I've looked and looked for posts on SO regarding how to form urllib requests in Python 3.4, but nothing has helped. I still can't get the page that I should be getting (the results page that shows which classes are offered when/where/etc...)

Here's how I form the request:

```
post_data = {'Submit':           'Display Web Results',
             'YearTer':          '2014-92',
             'ShowComments':     'on',
             'ShowFinals':       'on',
             'Breadth':          'ANY',
             'Dept':             'I&C SCI',
             'CourseNum':        '',
             'Division':         'ANY',
             'CourseCodes':      '',
             'InstrName':        '',
             'CourseTitle':      '',
             'ClassType':        'ALL',
             'Units':           '',
             'Days':             '',
             'StartTime':        '',
             'EndTime':          '',
             'MaxCap':           '',
             'FullCourses':      'ANY',
             'FontSize':         '100',
             'CancelledCourses': 'Exclude',
             'Bldg':             '',
             'Room':             ''}

urlencoded_post_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(post_data)
binary_post_data = urlencoded_post_data.encode('utf-8')
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml'}
request = urllib.request.Request(url, data=binary_post_data, headers=header)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

And the webpage I get in response is the same page, instead of the results page containing all I&C Sci classes.

Could anyone help? I'm fairly sure that I'm forming the request correctly (famous last words). I've inspected what the response should look like if I were to do it through the browser, and I can't seem to solve it.

Comment: Don't quote me on this but I think that if you call urlencode on the data it's gonna make a get request. Try removing the urlencode line and the one after it.

Comment: Just for the future reference, [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) gives easier HTTP requests for Python

Comment: @IonutHulub Do you have a source for that? That could make sense as to why I'm getting these results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in `'YearTerm'` parameter. It works as expected when it's correct.

Comment: Thanks! More than one pair of eyes always helps catch these bugs. It works perfectly. Great catch.